# Replace Elements in a Dataset by rules

Tags: dataset

I've got a dataset with 100+ various columns. I want to change e.g. the values 0 and 1 in the first column with "male" and "female". In the second column i'd like to change the 0 and 1 with e.g. "alive" or "dead".

When applying following code, it does not produce the desired output since the values don't get overwritten in my dataset called data even though my first column has the correct header "Gender" with all the Associations. How can it be achieved?

```
data[ReplaceAll[{1 -> "Male", 0 -> "Female"}],"Gender"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For discussion, let us consider the following dataset:

```
data = Dataset @ Table[
  <|"Gender" -> RandomInteger[1], "Status" -> RandomInteger[1], "Data" -> RandomReal[]|>
, 4
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

A query will not update a dataset in place.  Rather, it generates a new dataset containing the result.  So, using the query from the question (without the trailing semicolon which suppresses the output) we see:

```
data[ReplaceAll[{1 -> "Male", 0 -> "Female"}], "Gender"]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This shows the correctly altered *Gender* column.  But only that column.  This is because the `"Gender"` operator projects out the column with that name:

```
data[All, "Gender"]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Note that the original dataset is left untouched.

If we wish to generate a new dataset with transformed *Gender* and *Status* columns, we must apply query operators to only those columns.  We can do this by name:

```
data[
  All
, { "Gender" -> Replace[{1 -> "Male", 0 -> "Female"}]
  , "Status" -> Replace[{1 -> "Alive", 0 -> "Dead"}]
  }
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

... or by column index (1 = *Gender*, 2 = *Status*):

```
data[
  All
, { 1 -> Replace[{1 -> "Male", 0 -> "Female"}]
  , 2 -> Replace[{1 -> "Alive", 0 -> "Dead"}]
  }
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

In both cases, a new complete dataset is returned with the original remaining untouched.