# Match & replace the elements in a dataset

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, dataset

somewhat similarly to [Replace Elements in a Dataset by rules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/173753/replace-elements-in-a-dataset-by-rules), I'd like to replace the components in all columns named "microseconds" in a hierarchical dataset, with their respective quantity. 
Something like:

`Replace[ myDataSet, Rule["microseconds", x_Integer] -> Rule["microseconds", Quantity[x, "Microseconds"], All]`

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for the answers! Unfortunately they don't fit yet with my case, for instance the input is more something like: https://gist.github.com/whatsthecraic/05d7f68c38b722c90ca52216980f502a

Answer (score 1):

My attempt (using initial input from @Tomi answer):

```
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"Data 1", "Data 2", "Microseconds"} -> #] & /@ 
     Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 10}]]
```

Now to change "Microseconds" column we apply appropriate function to it:

```
ds[All, {"Microseconds" -> (Quantity[#, "Microseconds"] &)}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you are looking for. But lets say your data looks like:

```
    (* make fake data *) 

mydataset = 
  Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {i, 1, 10}];
mydataset = Prepend[mydataset, {"Data 1", "Data 2", "Microseconds"}];
MatrixForm[mydataset]
```

[image]

We could do something like

```
mydataset[[2 ;;, {3}]] = 
 Quantity[#, "Microseconds"] & /@ mydataset[[2 ;;, {3}]]
```

What I'm doing here is selecting all values from the second line to the last line, and then the `{3}`rd column. I then use `Map` (aka `&/@`) to apply the function `Quantity[]` to this dataset, and this results in: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `UnitConvert` with `Quantity` if the column is not already a `Quantity`.

```
SeedRandom[123];
RandomSample[ResourceData["Sample Data: Titanic Survival"], 10][All,
  <|#, "Age" -> UnitConvert[#Age, "Microseconds"]|> &]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my issue with [KeyValuePattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValuePattern.html)

The final expression becomes:

```
ds[Replace[ #, 
   match : KeyValuePattern["microseconds" -> t_] :> 
    Append[ KeyDrop[match, "microseconds"], 
     "microseconds" ->  Quantity[t, "Microseconds"]], All ] &]
```